# SSIS Package Failing on Executing Job

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Good Day,

I imported a package from SSIS to SQL to run as a Job.
if i manually execute the Package in SSIS in MSSMS it executes successful
as soon as i run it as a job i get the following error:

> Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE. Microsoft (R) SQL Server
>   Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.1600.1 for 64-bit  Copyright
>   (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started: 
>   12:10:22 PM  Error: 2014-08-14 12:10:22.07     Code: 0xC0016016
>   Source:       Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node
>   "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in
>   specified state.". You may not be authorized to access this
>   information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error.
>   Verify that the correct key is available.  End Error  Error:
>   2014-08-14 12:10:22.24     Code: 0xC0202009     Source:
>   TritonFuelImport Connection manager "41.160.218.141.CCManager.sa"
>   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has
>   occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.  An OLE DB record is available. 
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D
>   Description: "Login failed for user 'sa'.".  End Error  Error:
>   2014-08-14 12:10:22.24     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: Data Flow Task
>   OLE DB Destination [15]     Description: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager
>   "41.160.218.141.CCManager.sa" failed with error code 0xC0202009. 
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
>   on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  End Error  Error:
>   2014-08-14 12:10:22.24     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Data Flow Task
>   SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component "OLE DB Destination" (15)
>   failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.  End Error 
>   Error: 2014-08-14 12:10:22.24     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Data
>   Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed
>   validation.  End Error  Error: 2014-08-14 12:10:22.24     Code:
>   0xC0024107     Source: Data Flow Task      Description: There were
>   errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package
>   execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  12:10:22 PM 
>   Finished: 12:10:22 PM  Elapsed:  0.187 seconds.  The package execution
>   failed.  The step failed.

Can someone Please assist to help me solve this problem?

Comment: "You may not be authorized to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error. Verify that the correct key is available."

Comment: "Login failed for user 'sa'."

Comment: Yes i understand the error on sa but why is if failing it is working in Visual Studio?
AM i compiling the Package incorrectly or how can i solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

When you execute the package from Visual Studio, it is run under your user principal. When it's run through the SQL Agent, it's executed under the account SQL Server is set up with (either Local Service or a domain account set up for this purpose). Now, one part of your package (probably a connection manager) has properties called EncryptSensitive and ProtectionLevel (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141747.aspx) and by default this is set to your user account.

When SQL Agent tries to execute, it can't decrypt the sensitive data on the connection manager (probably the password) using its own keys. There are two ways of resolving:

- Set the Protection level to something different
- Create an SQL Agent Proxy with your credentials and set up the job to use that when executing this package (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189064(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is a property you need to change in visual studio data tools. Have a look in the properties tab, there is an option for encryption of passwords. There are 3 different options from memory. If that doesn't work, try going to security in SQL server management studio then credentials. Then click add credential and add the credential of the user that successfully runs the job. Then in your job step, go into the step and set "run as" to the credential you created. I would also check the advanced tabs of the job step, to make sure the properties for the username and password are correct, sometimes they don't get deployed from data tools and you have to manually add them to the job step run by the agent.